# How to extend 3rd party class in a generic way in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-class, typescript-generics

**tl;dr**: I want to extend 3rd-party lib's class in a nice way. But how?

Let's say I have a 3rd party lib that creates very generic entity `Animal`:

```
class Animal {
  type: string;
}
```

I want to create a `cat` and a `dog`:

```
const dog = new Animal({type: 'dog'});
const cat = new Animal({type: 'cat'});
```

**But** in terms of types both of them will be `Animal` anyway. In future I want to have functions that accepts only `Cat` but not `Dog`.

The only idea I have in mind is to create functions, like:

```
function createCat(): Cat {
  return  new Animal({type: 'cat'}) as Cat;
}

class Cat extends Animal {}
```

But that approach has many downsides:

- I'll have extra classes in runtime;
- I have to describe each class (cat, dog) manually;
- I've got to cast types (`return ... as Cat`) in each "create" function;

**What I'd want** to see is something like:

```
function createCat(): Animal<Cat> {
  return ...;
}
```

Is it possible? Or maybe any different approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

a) not sure all your "downsides" are such horrible downsides per se.

b) take a look at the example at the bottom of this page:

```
class BeeKeeper {
    hasMask: boolean;
}

class ZooKeeper {
    nametag: string;
}

class Animal {
    numLegs: number;
}

class Bee extends Animal {
    keeper: BeeKeeper;
}

class Lion extends Animal {
    keeper: ZooKeeper;
}

function createInstance<A extends Animal>(c: new () => A): A {
    return new c();
}

createInstance(Lion).keeper.nametag;  // typechecks!
createInstance(Bee).keeper.hasMask;   // typechecks!
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Generics.md

Comment: This won't work for me: In my case - I don't want to extend structure, the difference will be only in data. So in terms of typescript `Cat`, `Dog`, and `Animal` will be same type, so you won't be able to write function that accept `Cat` but not accept `Dog`.

Comment: Then, make it the same, it doesn't have to have different fields.